# How to change the excerpt depending on category - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering how to change the excerpt depending on category in WordPress. I have changed the default amount but I need this amount for some boxes on the home page and I need it to display more words on the blog page of the website.

Thanks,
Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a custom excerpt that you can use and change as you wish. I've recently done a complete answer on `the_excerpt()`. This comes from that answer. You can also check out the complete answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141136/31545)

**CUSTOM EXCERPT LENGTHS**

Sometimes you need to display simple excerpts of different lengths and it is not viable to write an excerpt for every post/function/page. Here is a nice small little function using `wp_trim_words`

```
function wpse_custom_excerpts($limit) {
    return wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), $limit, '<a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&hellip;' . __( 'Read more &nbsp;&raquo;', 'wpse' ) . '</a>');
}
```

What this little function do is taking `get_the_excerpt` trimming that to `$limit` set by the user and returning the text with a read more link at the end.

You can call this excerpt as follow in your template

```
echo wpse_custom_excerpts($limit);
```

where `$limit` will be your word count, so an excerpt of 30 word will be

```
echo wpse_custom_excerpts(30);
```

Just one thing to remember here, if you set your limit to more that 55 words, only 55 words will be returned as the excerpt is only 55 words in length. If longer excerpts are needed, use `get_the_content` instead.

Comment: Great explanation took a couple of seconds with your help, its one of them things once you've done once you shall remember so thank you very much for making me understand. All the best.